# Importing zone file from godaddy to AWS encountered this error

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

I am trying to upload zone file from godaddy to AWS, when I copy paste the zone file content to AWS and click upload, the following error appeared:

[image: error message]

> Error parsing zone file: Error in line 38: Invalid address: >>++PARKED1++<< (encountered after 1 correct records)
> In line:
> @   600 IN  A   >>++PARKED1++<<

Comment: I'm guessing the **>>++PARKED1++<<** line must be a GoDaddy thing. That line is an A Record expecting an IP Address to point to, so you should probably try with the IP address that you want to point to.

Comment: @FrankChen hey do what IP address should we put in there to replace the >>++PARKED1++<<???

Answer (score 6):

It looks like your domain was 'parked' with GoDaddy at the time you tried to export you zone file. `>>++PARKED1++<<` is an internal variable which GoDaddy use in there DNS Db.

The actual record is an `A` record and you should just replace `>>++PARKED1++<<` with the external IP address of your hosting provider. (e.g 1.1.1.1)

After the change you should expect that line of the config file to read as;

`@    600    IN    A    1.1.1.1` (For example.)

The GoDaddy [help](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/export-my-domains-zone-file-records-4166) page also says;

> The exported data follows the BIND zone file format and RFC 1035. You
> must manually edit the exported data before a BIND DNS server can use
> it directly. These edits will differ based on the requirements of the
> server to which you are uploading the exported file.

But sadly it does not provide any useful pointers to the reader as to *what* exactly needs to be changed...

If you are mapping to an `elasticbeanstalk.com` endpoint then you *shouldn't* use an IP address (as they may change) and instead change the record type to `ALIAS` and then add the name of your endpoint `xxxx.elasticbeanstalk.com`

Comment: How do I find the public IP address of GoDaddy for example?. This answer is partially helpful only

Comment: @PrashanthY which public IP your comment is unclear and maybe incomplete.

Comment: No, it’s not incomplete. Sorry, hopefully this makes more sense. In the example above you said it may look like 1.1.1.1 but I don’t know where to find this IP address? Should I just instead add the elastic beanstalk url which would be something like hejdbhd.hkrhd.elasticbeanstalk.com

Comment: @PrashanthY Ahh I see what your asking now - in your case updated the A Record to ALIAS (by ticking Alias = Yes) then use the `hejdbhd.hkrhd.elasticbeanstalk.com` as the name. I will update my answer as well

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck exactly here for a while, and I think I might have an answer.

1. In place of the -parked- / missing 'a record' value, use the IP of the current application with a temporary adress. 
   For example, the IP address of example.eu-north-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
2. If unknown this IP address can also be found at www.whatsmydns.net.
   Just type in the temporary address (e.g. the EB url address above) and the IP will show.
   I.e. this is the -A Record- to use in place of the word -Parked-... copy & paste.

---

A second update on this..
After a couple of days I learnt that method above did not work too well.
Essentially, the A - IPv4 address of my EB app kept changing every so often.

Instead I updated the A Record to ALIAS (by ticking Alias = Yes) then entered the address of my EB app. Example xxxxxx.elasticbeanstalk.com

So far this has worked..

Answer (score 1):

Just remove that line and use import. After the import, you can add the alias to the IP address

Comment: This worked for me. Need to make sure while using alias that you are not reusing existing name.